# Make accordeon/toggle menu using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Found a solution:

```
$('div.divname').not(':eq(0)').hide();
```

Check this page:

http://www.iloja.pt/index.php?_a=viewDoc&docId=19

I would like to have ONLY the first text (faqtexto) open, and the one bellow, hidden on loading (by default)

This is the HTML:

```
    <div class="agendarfaq">
        <div class="topfaq"></div>

        <div class="faqtopics"><p class="textopics">Recolha e entrega, quanto tempo?</p></div>
        <div class="faqtexto"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem   ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem</div>

        <div class="faqtopics"><p class="textopics">Recolha e entrega, quanto tempo?</p></div>
        <div class="faqtexto"> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem   ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem</div>
    </div>
```

The jQuery I propose:

```
$(".faqtopics").click(function(event) {
    $("div.faqtexto").slideUp(100);
    $(this).next("div.faqtexto").slideToggle();
});
```

Do you suggest any other cleaner jQuery code?

Any help would be welcome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead of jQuery?

```
style="display: none;"
```

on your HTML elements you want to be hidden on page load.

Then with jQuery...

```
$("#MyElement").toggle();
```

...to toggle the element.

Comment: By doing one by one, the code will not look that clean... I like things automated

Comment: In that case you could use an additional class for your hidden elements instead of styling in HTML.

Comment: found a solution: 

$('div.faqtexto').not(':eq(0)').hide();

thank you;